# Trouble with bootstrap columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble with bootstrap's columns.

The problem is that `col-xs-8` padding exceeds the parent row width and creates a horizontal scroll bar. But if I remove the padding then `col-xs-8` is pulled right by the amount of padding removed. For example when padding is `15px` and I remove it the `col-xs-8` is moved right by the same amount.

My HTML

```
<div ng-cloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-style="{'margin-left':marginLeft}" class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <!--tabs-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div id="canvasContainer">
                <canvas></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use `overflow-x:hidden`.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with

```
 <div ng-style="{'margin-left':marginLeft}" class="col-xs-4">
```

As much you will give margin-left it will go right..You need to give padding-left in left div to control this structure.

Comment: I use margin-left to hide col-xs-4 from users point of view. At first marginLeft is zero and when it's hidden marginLeft is equal to negative width of col-xs-4. So why should it mess up the padding?

Comment: Actual problem was solved by `.col-xs-8 {
 padding: 0px;
}` but your answer got me thinking in the right direction. Thanks!